# Pycharm устанавливает пакеты мимо venv

Tags: python, django, cmd, pycharm

Установил venv через стандартный create project в Pycharm. То что используется venv в терминале подсвечивается, но при попытке установки пакетов, терминал ссылается на стандартную папку [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VtXr.png]  Пытался изменить через интерпретатор, но ничего не меняется. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И скрин терминала [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Деактивирую и активирую venv, но ничего не меняется, так же глобальные пакеты. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои переменные среды и Path [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы начал с убирания из путей кириллицы. Даже если не поможет щас - поможет в будущем.

Comment: Окей, сделаю :) Но лучше бы по теме..

Comment: Тебе разбираться нужно с path переменной среды, как я думаю

Comment: Я смотрел path,  там нет ничего страшного, стандартный путь, сейчас добавлю дополнение к посту.